# Android(Eclipse) Startactivity gives no response

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to Java and android programming. I added a code to switch  between interfaces to my application after a toast message but when i start program, after toast message it just stays in the same interface without giving any errors.

```
try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx/xxx.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler); 
        String reverseString = response;
        if (reverseString =="success"){
            Toast.makeText(this, reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            startActivity(new Intent(registergame.this, (MainActivity.class)));
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

and my manifest file;

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".deneme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.baglanti.DENEME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".registergame"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.baglanti.REGISTER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also tried

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));
```

but same thing happens, it shows toast message and stays like that, any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In startActivity(new Intent(registergame.this, (MainActivity.class)));  Instead of using registergame.this, try using getApplicationContext() .

Comment: Did you saw this toast Toast.makeText(this, reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: ashwin, you wrote the same thing, i posted :(

Comment: Amsheer yes toast message is seen but after that nothing happens :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once i also face same kind of issue. When i need to read response and if it "success" then allow to next Activity. In my case i have issue with the "if" condition. That is  instead of this `if (reverseString =="success")`

just try

```
if (reverseString.contains("success"))
```

I want to say this in comment. But it's lengthy so saying here. Maybe it will help. I am not sure.

Note : @Reply for comment
You must saw the Toast. Because you add same thing in if and else so. remove the Toast from else and see you can't see the toast. That is because your if condition fails.

Comment: Wow it worked, ty very much Amsheer, i didnt think "if" may cause this kind of error as the toast message was seen.

Comment: Sorry my English weak. I don't understand. What you mean. Is my answer working or not ?

Comment: i will, it doesnt let me accept it before a few minutes pass after the question is created.